# Read binary file from C# on NodeJs?

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, binary, unity-container

Is it possible to read a binary file made on C# (Unity App), using NodeJS?

Am using Node-Webkit and i've never used anything other than c# to read/create my binary files to save stuff, is there a type convention or a key that i need to know to be able to read and build the binary data from nodejs perspective so i can print it in a interface?

```
public static void Save() {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create (Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd");
        bf.Serialize(file, SaveLoad.savedGames);
        file.Close();
}
```

Comment: Did you already tried to read that binary in nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of `fs.read()`-ing the first 100 bytes from a file descriptor returned by `fs.open()`:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.open('file.txt', 'r', function(error, fd) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        return;
    }
    var buffer = new Buffer(100);
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, 100, 0, function(err, num) {
        console.log(buffer.toString('utf-8', 0, num));
    });
});
```